# Process uploaded file content in Servlet and print the content in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, apache-commons, apache-commons-fileupload

First i must state that i'm jsp/servlet rookie trying to learn it's mechanisms.
**INTRO:**
Since i read [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/eclipse-file-upload-servlet-with-apache-common-file-upload) tutorial on using *Apache-Commons-FileUpload 3.0*, Servlet uploads .txt file successfully, and the file gets stored in Tomcat's *wtpwebapps/MyProject/upload* folder.
Here is the important part of UploadServlet's doPost method, it's just the same as in referenced tutorial:

```
try {
        // parses the request's content to extract file data
        List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
        Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

        // iterates over form's fields
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            // processes only fields that are not form fields
            if (!item.isFormField()) {
                String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                File storeFile = new File(filePath);                     
                // saves the file on disk
                item.write(storeFile);
            }
        }
        request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        request.setAttribute("message", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

}

At the end of code segment, programmer specifies *message* text that will be printed in */messages.jsp* file.

**QUESTION:**
Before setting the request attribute, how can i obtain an uploaded file as stream, do something with it line by line (using *BufferedReader* or similar), close the stream and send it as... *String[]* for example, to */message.jsp* via container's request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FileItem` has a [`getInputStream()`](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html#getInputStream%28%29) method. Call it, read the file using the returned input stream, fill a `List<String>` with its contents, and add the list as an attribute to the request.

Comment: Mersi, for your time and this simple answer, i'm litle imbaresed now, salut! :)

Comment: hey guys, can you give little more details how i can read a txt file using  getInputStream()  method and process the data after uploading the file?? i am stuck with this process. :(